# Excel VBA: How to set properties of unknown object in array to null?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array Arr() that contains objects of unknown class. I want to set all properties of Arr(i) to null.

How can I achieve this?

```
Set Arr(i) = NULL
```

would be nice, but doesn't work

Comment: Do you mean you want to set all the properties of the object in Arr(i) to null or set Arr(i) to null?

Comment: There is no such thing as "NULL" in VBA. You must use the keyword "Nothing".

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Erase` to clear the array. See below

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Ar(1 To 2)

    Ar(1) = "Sid"
    Ar(2) = "1.1"

    Debug.Print Ar(1)
    Debug.Print Ar(2)

    Erase Ar

    Debug.Print ">"; Ar(1)
    Debug.Print ">>"; Ar(2)
End Sub
```

SNAPSHOT

[image]